# How to use CppSharp

Tags: c#, cppsharp

I want to use CppSharp to create a C# wrapper for some classes from a C++ library which I intend to use from C# (on a 64 Bit Windows 10 system).

Unfortunately I am absolutely uncertain how to proceed. I cloned CppSharp into my filesystem and built it as described in the 'Getting started' section

https://github.com/mono/CppSharp/blob/main/docs/GettingStarted.md

I also ran all the test successfully.

From what I read in the documentation I was under the impression that to use CppSharp one has to create a C# application (for simplicity a console application), implement an abstract class from CppSharp and execute some commands from CppSharp. From

https://github.com/mono/CppSharp/issues/82

EDIT: Now I use the following code

```
using CppSharp;
using CppSharp.AST;
using CppSharp.Generators;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CppSharpTransformer
{

    class DllDemoGenerator : ILibrary
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleDriver.Run(new DllDemoGenerator());
        }

        void Setup(Driver driver)
        {

            var options = driver.Options;
            options.GeneratorKind = GeneratorKind.CSharp;
            var module = options.AddModule("Sample");
            module.IncludeDirs.Add(@"C:\Users\Boehm.J\Documents\CppSharpSamples\Sample\include");
            module.Headers.Add("Sample.h");
            module.LibraryDirs.Add(@"C:\Users\Boehm.J\Documents\CppSharpSamples\Sample\lib");
            module.Libraries.Add("Sample.lib");

        }

        public void SetupPasses(Driver driver) { }

        public void Preprocess(Driver driver, ASTContext ctx)
        {
        }

        public void Postprocess(Driver driver, ASTContext ctx)
        {
        }

        void ILibrary.Setup(Driver driver)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

which is in Program.cs of my Console application I called CppSharpTransformer.

I could make it compile ok (Visual Studio 2022, Console Project with NET 6.0) by adding the following DLLs to my project:

CppSharp.AST.dll

CppSharp.CLI.dll

CppSharp.CppParser.dll

CppSharp.dll

CppSharp.Generator.dll

CppSharp.Parser.Bootstrap.dll

CppSharp.Parser.CLI.dll

CppSharp.Parser.CSharp.dll

CppSharp.Parser.dll

CppSharp.Parser.Gen.dll

CppSharp.Runtime.dll

I added them under "Dependencies (Abhängigkeiten) > Assemblys" and also as files as members of my project.

But I can not execute the application currently, as I get the runtime error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'CppSharp.Parser.CLI, Version=0.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Das System kann die angegebene
> Datei nicht finden.

(The german text says "The system can not find the specified file").

But the dll of this name is, it seems, in place. It occurs in

> C:\Users\Boehm.J\Documents\work\CppSharpTransformer\CppSharpTransformer

and in

> C:\Users\Boehm.J\Documents\work\CppSharpTransformer\CppSharpTransformer\bin\x64\Release\net6.0

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into the same issue.
Make sure you copy the Ijwhost.dll into your application's output path. 
For example like this:

```
<Target Name="CopyNative" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\CppSharp\bin\Release_x64\Ijwhost.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```